How can I make more complex queries with comparisons on the date field in Room database if I store the date as String yyyy-mm--dd?
My current question is about how does ROOM database manages dates and timestamps? Working on my current project, I've just found out that if I store my date fields as Strings (yyyy-mm-dd to be more precise), I won't be able to make queries in which I compare the date fields because ROOM does not know how to work with Strings. To be more precise I would like to be able to make queries in which I get all the entries in a table between a start date and an end date currently stored as Strings. I've looked into the documentation:
Referencing complex data with Room
and found out the solution is to use TypeConverters and annotate your specific entities accordingly. However both the documentation and some stack overflow answers:
Room using date field
Type converter for String date to long
seem to focus solely on the case of converting from Long to Date and viceversa. I understand the case, but my specific scenario is that I introduce the transaction dates for instance, in the database by hand as Strings. I would like to know a method of converting those Strings in format yyyy-mm-dd to Long and then I could use the other hints.
Any help would be appreciated.

"I won't be able to make queries in which I compare the date fields because ROOM does not know how to work with Strings" -- Room definitely knows "how to work with Strings". However, we do not know how you want to "compare the date fields".  "However both the documentation and some stack overflow answers... seem to focus solely on the case of converting from Long to Date and viceversa" -- for a date-time value, representing it as a Long (e.g., milliseconds since the Unix epoch) is a recommended approach.

I want to make queries in which I compare using relational operators like >, >=, <=, those date Strings stored in the database. For instance, get all the transactions after a specific date, which I currently hold as a String in the upper mentioned format. From my preliminary findings I am not sure Room can do this kind on comparisons on plain text String values. I totally agree with the documentation, but for the moment I am not sure on the above topics.

"From my preliminary findings I am not sure Room can do this kind on comparisons on plain text String values" -- SQLite (and Room or other SQLite wrappers) can do >, >=, and <= comparisons on strings.

Ook. This sounds promising. So if I have a date field inside an entity, taken from the user input in the format mentioned above, is it possible to make a query in which I get all the entries between a start date and an end date simply by comparing the date values stored as Strings? I'm starting to think it is.

Yes, that should be possible. If you try it and encounter problems, you might consider opening a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] demonstrating what you tried and explaining what problems you encountered.

Thank you very much! I'm going to read that link.


I won't be able to make queries in which I compare the date fields because ROOM does not know how to work with Strings.

However as Room is a wrapper around SQLite, and that SQLite has built-in date and time functions, which includes handling dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd, you can, as long as the dates can be seen as valid/accepted datetime formats, utilise such functions on the String values.

see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
especially


A time value can be in any of the following formats shown below. The value is usually a string, though it can be an integer or floating point number in the case of format 12. 1. YYYY-MM-DD  ....

Therefore if a date is stored as yyyy-mm-dd, then you can use BETWEEN on the stored value. Furthermore due to the yyyy-mm-dd format being according to the significance of the values then comparisons between two such values can be undertaken without even using the datetime functions.
Perhaps consider the following SQLite demo:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ex01;
/* Creeate the table with just the one column */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ex01 (dateAsString TEXT);
/* Load the table with 1000 rows each have a date that is 1 day after the previous date */
WITH
    /* use a CTE (Common Table Expresssion aka a tempt table that exists for the duration of the execution) */
    cte(thedate) AS (
        SELECT '2024-03-01' /* The first date */
        UNION ALL SELECT date(thedate,'+1 days') /* recursively add rows */ 
        FROM cte
        LIMIT 1000 /* stop when 1000 rows have been processed/added */
    )
INSERT INTO ex01 SELECT * FROM cte;

/* Now select the date in various formats for a given range */
SELECT 
    *, /* actual stored data */
    datetime(dateAsString) AS string_ts, /* as datetime i.e. yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss*/
    strftime('%s',dateasstring) AS long_ts, /* as Long (timestamp) */
    date(dateasstring) AS string_date /* converted to itself */
FROM ex01
WHERE dateasstring BETWEEN '2024-03-05' AND '2024-03-10' /* showing that SQLite can handle date as yyyy-mm-dd in a BETWEEN */
UNION SELECT '','','',max(dateasstring) FROM ex01 /* Add a row that is JUST the date of the highest(latest) row */
UNION SELECT '','','',min(dateasstring) FROM ex01 /* Add a row that is JUST the data of the lowest(earliest) row */
;

/* Final selection of a range */
SELECT * FROM ex01 WHERE dateasstring BETWEEN '2024-06-05' /*e.g. :fromDate in Room*/ AND '2024-06-10' /* e.g. :toDate in Room */;
/* Cleanup demo */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ex01;

The first SELECT (which adds rows for lowest and highest  dates) shows:-


i.e.

the first row displayed is the lowest date (in the last column)
the next row is the highest date
the other rows are those BETWEEN the dates in the query, but showing how they can easily be extracted in other formats



The 2nd SELECT is more akin to what you would probably utilise, resulting in:-

In Room the 2nd select could be, for example:-
@Query("SELECT * FROM ex01 WHERE dateAsAstring BETWEEN :fromDate and :toDate")
fun getTheDates(fromDate: String, toDate: String): List<Ex01>

Actually convert the demo to Room, then first the @Entity annotated Ex01 class:-
@Entity
data class Ex01(
    @PrimaryKey
    val dateAsAString: String
)

An @Dao annotated interface:-
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {

    @Query("WITH " +
            "cte(thedate) AS (" +
            "SELECT '2024-03-01' /* The first date */" +
            "UNION ALL SELECT date(thedate,'+1 days') /* recursively add rows */ " +
            "FROM cte " +
            "LIMIT 1000 /* stop when 1000 rows have been processed/added */ " +
            ")" +
            "INSERT INTO ex01 SELECT * FROM cte;")
    fun specialInsert()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ex01 WHERE dateAsAString BETWEEN :fromDate and :toDate")
    fun getTheDates(fromDate: String, toDate: String): List<Ex01>
}


obviously not a typical means of inserting data

A suitable @Database annotated class e.g. :-
@Database(entities = [Ex01::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs
    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of the demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
} 

Finally some activity code so running the App does something:-
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        dao.specialInsert()
        getAndLogDatesInRange("2024-03-01","2024-03-10","EXT01")
        getAndLogDatesInRange("2025-03-01","2025-03-10","EXT02")

    }

    fun getAndLogDatesInRange(fromDate: String, toDate: String, tagSuffix: String) {
        for (r in dao.getTheDates(fromDate,toDate)) {
            Log.d("DBINFO_${tagSuffix}","Date From row is ${r.dateAsAString} (between ${fromDate} AND ${toDate})")
        }
    }
}

The Result after running the above (first run).
The log includes:-
2024-05-13 10:55:43.826 D/DBINFO_EXT01: Date From row is 2024-03-01 (between 2024-03-01 AND 2024-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.826 D/DBINFO_EXT01: Date From row is 2024-03-02 (between 2024-03-01 AND 2024-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.826 D/DBINFO_EXT01: Date From row is 2024-03-03 (between 2024-03-01 AND 2024-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.826 D/DBINFO_EXT01: Date From row is 2024-03-04 (between 2024-03-01 AND 2024-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.827 D/DBINFO_EXT01: Date From row is 2024-03-05 (between 2024-03-01 AND 2024-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.827 D/DBINFO_EXT01: Date From row is 2024-03-06 (between 2024-03-01 AND 2024-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.827 D/DBINFO_EXT01: Date From row is 2024-03-07 (between 2024-03-01 AND 2024-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.827 D/DBINFO_EXT01: Date From row is 2024-03-08 (between 2024-03-01 AND 2024-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.827 D/DBINFO_EXT01: Date From row is 2024-03-09 (between 2024-03-01 AND 2024-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.827 D/DBINFO_EXT01: Date From row is 2024-03-10 (between 2024-03-01 AND 2024-03-10)


2024-05-13 10:55:43.828 D/DBINFO_EXT02: Date From row is 2025-03-01 (between 2025-03-01 AND 2025-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.828 D/DBINFO_EXT02: Date From row is 2025-03-02 (between 2025-03-01 AND 2025-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.828 D/DBINFO_EXT02: Date From row is 2025-03-03 (between 2025-03-01 AND 2025-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.828 D/DBINFO_EXT02: Date From row is 2025-03-04 (between 2025-03-01 AND 2025-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.828 D/DBINFO_EXT02: Date From row is 2025-03-05 (between 2025-03-01 AND 2025-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.828 D/DBINFO_EXT02: Date From row is 2025-03-06 (between 2025-03-01 AND 2025-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.828 D/DBINFO_EXT02: Date From row is 2025-03-07 (between 2025-03-01 AND 2025-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.829 D/DBINFO_EXT02: Date From row is 2025-03-08 (between 2025-03-01 AND 2025-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.829 D/DBINFO_EXT02: Date From row is 2025-03-09 (between 2025-03-01 AND 2025-03-10)
2024-05-13 10:55:43.829 D/DBINFO_EXT02: Date From row is 2025-03-10 (between 2025-03-01 AND 2025-03-10)

i.e. clearly the respective data has been selected accordingly between the two dates both times.
And as App Inspection shows, the dates are stored in the database as Strings e.g. :-

